Hamiltonian flows and Poisson Brackets confusion
I have been using results from this paper in calculations. In sections 2.4 and 3.4 they perform a canonical transformation into new coordinates consisting of constants of motion.
My question is specifically about eq. 2.65. There they claim that the flow generated by $H_0$ on some observable $f$ is given by the Poisson bracket $\{H_0, f\}$. To me this seems entirely backwards as for example Hamiltonian flows are given by the bracket $\{\cdot, H\}$.
However it's entirely possible that my Hamiltonian mechanics is simply too rusty.

It is a historically non-standard sign convention, but I like use the same convention as these authors  as it minimizes the number of minus signs in other places. I always stress  that I am using a non standard convention in published papares though.

The problem is that they seem to mix up different conventions as in (2.56) they write the Hamiltonian equations and sue the opposite convention to (2.65)
